# Where is the classpath set for hadoop

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop2

Where is the classpath for hadoop set? 
When I run the below command it gives me the classpath. Where is the classpath set?

```
  bin/hadoop classpath
```

I'm using hadoop 2.6.0

Answer (score 9):

Open your bash profile (`~/.profile` or `~/.bash_profile`) for editing and add the following:

1. **export** `HADOOP_HOME="/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop"` **then** Replace with your own path
2. **export** `HADOOP_CLASSPATH=$(find $HADOOP_HOME -name '*.jar' | xargs echo | tr ' ' ':')`
   **Save** the changes and **reload**.
3. **source** `~/.profile`

Answer (score 6):

As said by almas shaikh it's set in `hadoop-config.sh`, but you could add more jars to it in `hadoop-env.sh`

Here is a relevant code from `hadoop-env.sh` which adds additional jars like capacity-scheduler and aws jar's.

```
export HADOOP_CONF_DIR=${HADOOP_CONF_DIR:-"/etc/hadoop"}

# Extra Java CLASSPATH elements.  Automatically insert capacity-scheduler.
for f in $HADOOP_HOME/contrib/capacity-scheduler/*.jar; do
  if [ "$HADOOP_CLASSPATH" ]; then
    export HADOOP_CLASSPATH=$HADOOP_CLASSPATH:$f
  else
    export HADOOP_CLASSPATH=$f
  fi
done

# ... some other lines omitted

# Add Aws jar
export HADOOP_CLASSPATH=$HADOOP_CLASSPATH:share/hadoop/tools/lib/*
```

Comment: Prefer `for f in $HADOOP_HOME/share/hadoop/tools/lib/*.jar; do
  export HADOOP_CLASSPATH=$HADOOP_CLASSPATH:$f
done` to just `export HADOOP_CLASSPATH=$HADOOP_CLASSPATH:share/hadoop/tools/lib/*`

Comment: What is the difference between simple export with wildcard and using for loop to add one by one..?

Answer (score 2):

When you run `hadoop` command, it sources a file `hadoop-config.sh` that resides in `$HADOOP_HDFS_HOME/libexec` which sets your classpath (CLASSPATH) by picking jars residing in various directories viz.

```
$HADOOP_HDFS_HOME/share/hadoop/mapreduce 
$HADOOP_HDFS_HOME/share/hadoop/common
$HADOOP_HDFS_HOME/share/hadoop/hdfs etc.
```

Comment: In hadoop 2.6.0 HADOOP_HOME is changed to HADOOP_PREFIX

Comment: Yeah either use that or use $HADOOP_HDFS_HOME.

Comment: When I run bin/hdfs dfs -put etc/hadoop input I get the below error.

put: `input': No such file or directory

HOw can I resolve this error?

Comment: So put [syntax](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r0.19.1/hdfs_shell.html#put) is `-put <local file location> <hdfs location>, i believe you are trying to say copy this file in directory "/input" i..e you are missing "/" root directory?

Answer (score 1):

As per [this blog post](http://code.bobarnott.com/2013/01/09/setting-the-hadoop_classpath/), it is in an environment variable named `HADOOP_CLASSPATH`. You can set it as you would any other environment variable, the specifics of which depend on which shell you use. If you use `bash`, then you can call like `export HADOOP_CLASSPATH=/path/to/wherever:/path/to/wherever/else`.

Comment: Thanks. It looks like the blog is not active anymore!

Answer (score 1):

I also encountered the problem and have solved it, but my hadoop version is 2.10.1.

I hope it have some help for people who use a newer hadoop version. So far, the following methods should have worked as well in the latest hadoop version 3.3.0.

You just need to edit your `.bashrc` or `.profile`, I will give an example of `.bashrc`.

```
# edit .bashrc
$ vim ~/.bashrc
```

Add `HADOOP_HOME`, `PATH` of hadoop bin direcotry and `HADOOP_CLASSPATH` in `.bashrc`.

```
# export HADOOP_HOME=${your hadoop install directory}, an example as follows:

export HADOOP_HOME=/usr/local/hadoop-2.10.1

export PATH=${HADOOP_HOME}/bin:${PATH}

export HADOOP_CLASSPATH=`hadoop classpath`
```

Then,

`$ source ~/.bashrc`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add classpath entries without changes to the installed files (eg, due to permission restrictions), you can use put a `.hadooprc` file in your home directory with following content:

```
hadoop_add_classpath /path/to/file1.jar
hadoop_add_classpath /path/to/file2.jar
```

The `.hadooprc` file gets sourced automatically by `hadoop-config.sh` if it exists.

Note this only adds classpath entries for the current user.