# Could not find or load main class org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar

Tags: hadoop, windows-10, hadoop2

I have installed Hadoop single node on Windows and trying to run my jar with it:

```
hadoop jar MYJAR -D mapreduce.job.user.classpath.first=true -D mapreduce.task.timeout=0 -D mapreduce.map.speculative=false -D mapreduce.map.memory.mb=8300 -D mapred.child.java.opts="-Xmx8000m -Xms8000m -Xss256m" ....
```

but it says

```
Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar
```

I don't have `HADOOP_CLASSPATH` set and don't know how to set it.

**UPDATE 1**

Setting `HADOOP_CLASSPATH` and `CLASSPATH` pointing to `hadoop-common-2.8.3.jar` didn't help.

**UPDATE 2**

Example program

```
hadoop jar share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-examples-2.8.3.jar grep input output 'dfs[a-z.]+'
```

works well!

Can it be that my JAR is dependent on wrong hadoop?

**UPDATE 3**

```
λ hadoop classpath
D:\Apps\hadoop-2.8.3\etc\hadoop;D:\Apps\hadoop-2.8.3\share\hadoop\common\lib\*;D:\Apps\hadoop-2.8.3\share\hadoop\common\*;D:\Apps\hadoop-2.8.3\share\hadoop\hdfs;D:\Apps\hadoop-2.8.3\share\hadoop\hdfs\lib\*;D:\Apps\hadoop-2.8.3\share\hadoop\hdfs\*;D:\Apps\hadoop-2.8.3\share\hadoop\yarn\lib\*;D:\Apps\hadoop-2.8.3\share\hadoop\yarn\*;D:\Apps\hadoop-2.8.3\share\hadoop\mapreduce\lib\*;D:\Apps\hadoop-2.8.3\share\hadoop\mapreduce\*;D:\Apps\hadoop-2.8.3\share\hadoop\common\hadoop-common-2.8.3.jar;
```

Comment: `HADOOP_CLASSPATH` or `CLASSPATH` needs to be far more than a single JAR file.. It should point at files within `HADOOP_HOME/` What does `hadoop classpath` produce? See - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28260653/where-is-the-classpath-set-for-hadoop

Comment: Who should set this? I found nothing in scripts?

Comment: The `hadoop` command by default will `source` (load) that `hadoop-env.sh` file. However... Windows is not supported well, so... You would have far more luck with the Hortonworks or Cloudera Sandboxes.