# How to install spark-bigquery-connector in the VM GCP?

Tags: python, apache-spark, hadoop, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I have VM image cluster Hadoop with spark install in the GCP but it's not a dataproc.
Can I install the spark bigquery connector without using dataproc?
if yes ,how can I do it?
I found this link to download the connector
https://github.com/GoogleCloudDataproc/spark-bigquery-connector

Comment: Can I ask why not to use Dataproc?

Comment: might considering for migration to other platform , same consideation here @DavidRabinowitz

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can download it from the GitHub site and install in your spark cluster. Alternatively, you can add the `--packages com.google.cloud.spark:spark-bigquery-with-dependencies_2.11:0.18.0` to your spark command (spark-submit/pyspark/spark-shell).

**Edit**

There are few options:

- When you run you spark app, run `pyspark <params> --packages com.google.cloud.spark:spark-bigquery-with-dependencies_2.11:0.18.0`. Same goes for running spark-submit or spark-shell
- Download the jar from [the repository](https://github.com/GoogleCloudDataproc/spark-bigquery-connector) and copy it to the `/usr/lib/spark/jars/` directory. Usually this is done with a script after the cluster is available (using init  action).
- Download the jars in runtime like you mentioned:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder \
  .config("spark.jars.packages", "com.google.cloud.spark:spark-bigquery-with-dependencies_2.11:0.18.0") \
  .getOrCreate()
```

Comment: Thank you David for your response,but can you please explain  how to install the connector after I download it from the github?what should be the command line?what do you mean by  "you can add the --packages com.google.cloud.spark:spark-bigquery-with-dependencies_2.11:0.18.0" ?did you mean adding this code :"from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder\
  .config("spark.jars.packages", "com.google.cloud.spark:spark-bigquery-with-dependencies_2.11:0.18.0")\
  .getOrCreate()"

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, your cluster is not a native Dataproc cluster. You created a set of instances (at least one) and installed manually a Hadoop cluster. This scenario is more like an on-prem Hadoop installation (using GCP infrastructure); unfortunately, the [bigquery connector documentation](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/tutorials/bigquery-connector-spark-example#pyspark) doesn't specify if it can be used outside Dataproc, but I would think it should since the connector is a jar file. In the section [Downloading and Using the Connector](https://github.com/GoogleCloudDataproc/spark-bigquery-connector#downloading-and-using-the-connector), you can download the latest version or a different one in case one of them doesn't work.

To install the connector in a GCP VM instance, it is needed to include it in the java classpath of your application:

1. Include it in a Spark directory already added in the java classpath. Or you can add a new entry (this change will be cleaned up when your session ends in the prompt):

   `export CLASSPATH=</path/to/bigquery-connector.jar>:$CLASSPATH`
2. Use the [--jars](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/tutorials/bigquery-connector-spark-example#providing_the_connector_to_your_application) option when submitting your spark application.

The options above will allow you to run spark jobs locally. To submit your jobs to your Hadoop cluster, you should ensure that the connector is included in its classpath as well, I recommend using `HADOOP_CLASSPATH`. This [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28260653/where-is-the-classpath-set-for-hadoop) has more details about it.

Answer (score 0):

## Documentation

Need to follow [Installing the connector](https://github.com/GoogleCloudDataproc/hadoop-connectors/blob/master/gcs/INSTALL.md) document.

## Download the connector jar file

Download the appropriate  jar depending on the scala version that compiled the Spark and note the **/path/to/jar**.

| version | Link |
| --- | --- |
| Scala 2.11 | `gs://spark-lib/bigquery/spark-bigquery-latest_2.11.jar` ([HTTP link](https://storage.googleapis.com/spark-lib/bigquery/spark-bigquery-latest_2.11.jar)) |
| Scala 2.12 | `gs://spark-lib/bigquery/spark-bigquery-latest_2.12.jar` ([HTTP link](https://storage.googleapis.com/spark-lib/bigquery/spark-bigquery-latest_2.12.jar)) |

## Cloud Storage access

Because your VM is in GCP, follow the instruction in the [Installing the connector](https://github.com/GoogleCloudDataproc/hadoop-connectors/blob/master/gcs/INSTALL.md) document.

> - **Google Cloud Platform** - Each Google Compute Engine VM must be [configured to have access](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/authentication#using) to the [Cloud Storage scope](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/authentication#oauth) you intend to use the connector for. When running inside of Google Compute Engine VMs, including Dataproc clusters, google.cloud.auth.service.account.enable is set to false by default, which means you don't need to manually configure a service account for the connector; it will automatically get the service account credential from the metadata server of the VM. But you must need to make sure the VM service account has permission to access the GCS bucket.

## Spark property

To tell Spark (both driver and executor) where to load the jar file, set the Spark property. Note that I am using Spark on YARN, so please adjust according to your cluster configuration.

```
spark = SparkSession.builder\
    .appName('spark-bigquery-demo') \
    .master('yarn') \
    .config('spark.submit.deployMode', 'client') \
    .config("spark.jars", "/path/to/jar") \
    .getOrCreate()
```

---

## For non GCP environment

### OAuth 2.0 private key

Run the GCP SDK command and generate the `application_default_credentials.json` file.

```
gcloud auth application-default login
```

Place the keyfile where the Spark submit account and executor account can access and read.

### Spark properties to set

> ```
> spark.hadoop.google.cloud.auth.service.account.enable       true
> spark.hadoop.google.cloud.auth.service.account.json.keyfile <path/to/keyfile.json>
> ```

No need to set the `spark.executorEnv.GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` property.

### Spark Session

```
spark = SparkSession.builder\
    .appName('spark-bigquery-demo') \
    .master('yarn') \
    .config('spark.submit.deployMode', 'client') \
    .config("spark.hadoop.google.cloud.auth.service.account.enable", "true") \
    .config("spark.hadoop.google.cloud.auth.service.account.json.keyfile", GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS) \
    .config("spark.jars", "/path/to/jar") \
    .getOrCreate()
```